# Usable Resolution limited on Mac Mini

Tags: screen, mac-mini

Since a few days, i have a limited Screen resolution, resulting in a black bar on the top and the bottom of the screen. When starting up in safe-boot, there is no prolbem. The display dialog let's me select the correct resolution 1920x1200, but beneath ther is written "Usable resolution 1920 x 1080"

Comment: What sort of monitor do you have, and what kind of cable connects it to the Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason are two displays (one tv) with "mirror displays" ticked.